# MySQL Incrementing ID/UUID Question

Tags: mysql, uuid, increment

i'm attempting to create a table with an incremental ID. This isn't the simple id with AUTO_INCREMENT. In fact, the exact ID that i'm trying to work with is:

test.script.1/person.n  (where n is an incrementing number)

Specifically, I have a table structured as:

ID | fname | lname | gender | age |

Each person that I add in, I wish to have and incremental ID. So for person 1, it would be test.script.1/person.1 and then test.script.1/person.2 for the second entry and so on and so forth.

Is it possible to do this? I have searched for a while now in Google, but I do not think I am searching for the right thing. My apologies if there isn't that much information, and it is a simple question, I just don't know what to look for. Please advise.

Thanks guys!

Comment: This doesn't make sense.  Can you please expand a little more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an autoincrementing field together with a trigger to populate the actual field you wish to use for your reference.

Something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER set_my_uuid AFTER INSERT ON myTable
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
SET NEW.uuid_ref_col = concat('test.script.1/person.', NEW.my_auto_increment_col)
END
;
```

where `my_auto_increment_col` is a standard autoincrement column in the table.

Comment: Would uuid_ref_col remain the same?

Comment: @Michael: In davek's example, you would not supply `my_auto_increment_col` or `uuid_ref_col` in your `INSERT` statement. They would both be generated, but it would produce what you want. You would just have an `auto_increment` column **and** the id column you want.

Comment: Ah, that makes much more sense, thank you for the clarification.

Comment: Actually, upon further research (now that I know what to look for), SET NEW.col_name = value does not work with the AFTER function. Only before.